# Show Combining of RegionPLot and ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

If I try:

```
RegionPlot[{y > x - 1 && y^2 < 2 x + 6}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -3, 5},
 Mesh -> None]
```

I get:

[image]

However, if I combine it with a ContourPlot:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[{y == x - 1, y^2 == 2 x + 6}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -3, 5},
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
 RegionPlot[{y > x - 1 && y^2 < 2 x + 6}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -3, 5},
  Mesh -> None]
 ]
```

I get this:

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of all the mesh-like segments in the image? I did try Mesh->None.

**Guess who it is idea worked:**

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[{y == x - 1, y^2 == 2 x + 6}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -3, 5},
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
 RegionPlot[{y > x - 1 && y^2 < 2 x + 6}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -3, 5}],
 Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}
 ]
```

Produced:

[image]

Comment: The cure is undocumented: try `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}` in `Show[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. That worked! Thanks. Is this something I should do a feedback report to Wolfram?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Now, [it is documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html#362967291).

Comment: @Michael, finally… :)